# Cant fetch the content of some tabular data from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written Python 3 script which uses [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to extract data from a table within an [IFrame](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) from Rooster Resource. This table contains the [MLB Schedule for 2018](https://www.rosterresource.com/mlb-schedule-grid/).

However, when the script is executed I receive the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
```

when it reaches the line containing `iframe` within my script. Why is this the case?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("link above")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe#pageswitcher-content")))))
for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.waffle tr"))):
    data = [item.text for item in items.find_element_by_css_selector("td")]
    print(data)

driver.quit()
```

Btw, If you browse the above link you can see the table containing different colorful logos and texts

FYI, I don't wish to resuse the link within that iframe; rather, I wanna switch to it to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two nested iframes in that page to reach the content. Try this instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("above link")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")))))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe#pageswitcher-content")))))
for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.waffle tr"))):
    data = [item.text for item in items.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")]
    print(data)

driver.quit()
```